# Using WIX to install / configure MS loop back adaptor

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5, wix3.6, wix-extension

Is it possible to install and or configure (if already installed) Microsoft loop back adapter on XP/WIN7 using  MSI. Is it possible to do this using WiX 3.5 or above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found these links it might help to integrate the install and configuration of MS Loop Back.

[Manual install](http://www.webxpert.ro/andrei/2008/01/02/microsoft-loopback-adapter-manual-install-on-2000-xp-2003-vista/) 
[Automate install](http://www.webxpert.ro/andrei/2008/01/10/microsoft-loopback-adapter-automated-install/) 
[Automatic Configure](http://www.webxpert.ro/andrei/2008/01/10/microsoft-loopback-adapter-automated-configure/)

Create a dialog in the User Interface of your Wix install, that will pass the values to be configured on the machine.

Comment: Adding to this,  DevCon is not redistributable.  The web page says source is provided to teach you how to use the underlying APIs.  This would all have to be translated into WiX custom actions / XML.